# "select" dropdown section of simple html form resists css styling

Tags: html, css, forms, select, width

I have a rather simple webform to take in names, emails, and a dropdown box is provided to select what kind of device people are using. Every section except the select (dropdown list) is conforming to the css style.  The select ignores the width expression listed below as well. No solution I've found online expands it to meet the 190px length. (It's height also bucks any attempt to change it.) Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Select section of html code:

```
Device Type:<br />
<select name="Dtype" style="width: 150px">
<option value="iPad">iPad</option>
<option value="iPhone">iPhone</option>
<option value="AndroidTablet">Android Tablet</option>
<option value="AndroidPhone">Android Phone</option></select>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 5px;
}

input, textarea { 
    padding: 9px; 
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5; 
    outline: 0; 
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
    width: 190px; 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px); 
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    } 

input:hover, textarea:hover, 
input:focus, textarea:focus { 
    border-color: #C9C9C9; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px; 
    } 

select { 
    padding: 9px; 
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5; 
    outline: 0; 
    width: 190px;
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px); 
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    }    



.form label { 
    margin-left: 10px; 
    color: #999999; 
    } 

.submit input { 
    width: auto; 
    padding: 9px 15px; 
    background: #617798; 
    border: 0; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type=number] {
-moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: I Checked your code the width and height of the select are getting changed. You have written inline CSS as ' style="width: 150px" ' remove this and your styling will come from CSS file then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove  style="width: 150px" from select tag, inline styling always overrides the style applied via css.

If you remove inline styling it will pick the style applied in css.

Comment: Oi dumb mistake on my part, that did it.  However in order to get it to line up I must now set the select width as 210px and everything else 190px. Where is the 20px difference coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You must delete `style="width: 150px"` from html, or use !important in css: `width: 190px !important;`
The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:

- Universal selectors
- Type selectors
- Class selectors
- Attributes selectors
- Pseudo-classes ID selectors
- Inline style

Answer (score 1):

The css is working as expected. As far as the width is concerned, that is because you have inline style which overrites the css rules.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/558/

HTML:

```
Device Type:
<br />
<select name="Dtype">
    <option value="iPad">iPad</option>
    <option value="iPhone">iPhone</option>
    <option value="AndroidTablet">Android Tablet</option>
    <option value="AndroidPhone">Android Phone</option>
</select>
```